# Angular bind to the status of a promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I've got a promise from, for example, and HTTP request:

```
$scope.myHttpPost = $http.post(…);
```

Is it possible to bind to the status (loading / done / error) in a template?

For example, something like:

```
<div ng-switch on="myHttpPost.status">
    <span ng-switch-when="'loading'">Loading…</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="'done'">Success!</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="'error'">Error :(</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to store your HTTP requests in the scope. Using and changing `$scope.status` should be simple enough.

Comment: Can you clarify why it's a bad idea to store the request on `$scope`?

Comment: That's not a bad idea, but that's useless, since you can't use a promise in a template (promise unwrapping is disabled since a while in AngularJS). Better to store them in a local variable.

Comment: @DavidWolever because you are storing the entire contents of `myHttpPost` in the scope rather than the one variable you require

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you can do this with any built in method. However it isn't that hard to setup a reusable promise wrapping system to get the variables you are looking for. To use the words you wanted in your example, you could do something like:

```
// function inside service
function newStatus(promise) {
    var status = {
        label: 'loading'
    };

    promise.then(function(){
        status.label = 'done';
    });

    promise.catch(function(){
        status.label = 'error';
    });

    return status;
}
```

Then you set it up where you call `$http` like so:

```
var promise = $http.post(...);
$scope.httpStatus = Status.newStatus(promise);
```

Then reference it in your html like so:

```
<div ng-switch on="httpStatus.label">
    <span ng-switch-when="'loading'">Loading…</span>
</div>
```

---

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/hw0pkgp0/